# Session got reset in chrome

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, google-chrome

I have two domains `abc.com` and `xyz.com` in one server,both have the exact code.The problem is in xyz.com the codeigniter session variable got reset on page refresh in chrome browser.But there is no such issues in abc.com.It works fine in Mozilla in both domains.What will be the root of issue?Is it related with domain,htaccess?Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this (or a very similar) issue before, and i solved it by enabling sessions to use the database.

i.e in the config.php , make sess_use_database to true, i.e

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']         = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE; //you can try this with TRUE and see if it works
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

make sure the session table is set in the database as well. if not, here is the sql,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
  `session_id` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip_address` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_agent` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `last_activity` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_data` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `session_data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: this was also there.but issue still remains

Comment: confirm this please, because if sessions are being stored on database (and not with cokkies), it makes no sense that the result would be different on different browsers.

as ramiro suggested, try playing around with the config variables. I have updated my post with what i think your session config variables should be.